# API to get the deleted file name

Tags: c++, c, windows, filesystems

Is there any mechanism to get the file name when user is deleting the file on windows explorer. Whether it is possible at the application level?

Comment: Is this delete to Recycle Bin or Shift Delete?

Comment: There should be a way to subscribe to a *delete* file event. Google that maybe

Comment: I would like to get file name in both the cases (Delete and shift Delete).

Answer (score 0):

Register an `ICopyHook` extension, check `ICopyHook::CopyCallback` for flag `FO_DELETE`. (despite the name, the hook is also called for moves and deletes).